# Wordpress магазин

Tags: wordpress

Подскажите есть ли еще магазинные плагины на wordpress помимо woocommerce, в которых будут уже вшитые личный кабинет, корзина и на русском языке желательно?

Comment: Чем вас WooCommerce не устраивает?

Comment: А еще такой вопрос, есть ли в woocommerce возможность чата из личного кабинета клиента скажем с менеджером?

Comment: В woocommerce такой возможности нет

Answer (score 1):

Вот, например:

- [Easy Digital Downloads](https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-digital-downloads/)
- [WP eCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-e-commerce/)
- [Ecwid Ecommerce Shopping Cart](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ecwid-shopping-cart/)
- [Jigoshop eCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jigoshop-ecommerce/)
- [WP EasyCart Shopping Cart and eCommerce Store](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-easycart/)

Comment: На такие вопросы не нужно отвечать) Они нарушают правила SO

Comment: @Krya почему это нарушают? Какие именно правила?

Comment: @SeVlad на данный вопрос невозможно дать объективный ответ, поэтому его закрыли)

Comment: @Krya вопрос, конечно ламерский, но формулировка "невозможно дать объективный ответ" не катит - ответ очень даже можно дать. Что  подтверждает данный ответ. А что до "закрыли", то кроме тебя остальные из голосующих - вредители.  Они сами в ВП нифига не понимают, и постоянно мешают юзерам и получать и оказывать помощь. У меня складывается ощущение, что у них цель - избавиться от ВП на ruSO.